# How to record the movement of robot arm?

Tags: ros, kinova

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to record the movement of a robot arm am play it back? I am using a kinova jaco arm.

Is there any available stack for the movement recording?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247309/how-to-record-the-movement-of-robot-arm?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Baxter research robot does this using joint recorder [here](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Joint_Trajectory_Playback_Example). Not sure how extensible it is to other robots, but it is a start.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0